# InvalidAbsFile error when running "stack" on windows in an existing project

Tags: windows, haskell, haskell-stack

Trying to use stack on an existing project that I have downloaded elsewhere

I have installed stack fine, and stack/haskell works fine when I create a new project project

But when I go to stack setup or run GHCI on an existing project (for context a project for uni) I keep running into this error when running
"stack setup"
"stack ghci"
most stack commands

InvalidAbsFile "C:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\ghc-8.8.2.exe"

(the file path is just where the file is located, removed it as its unecessary)

I have no clue what this means. Can anyone help?

Comment: The `"C:"C:` bit looks very weird. Did you manually configure this path in some way? Otherwise this might be a stack bug. In any case, I think you should report this on stack's issue tracker.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue, after the first C: is the file path, one my path variable had some dodgy java thing that was messing it around.